# Does the law of motion remain constant in a rational expectation model? Does it constantly change in a boundedly rational agent framework?

Tags: macroeconomics, rational-expectations, bounded-rationality

Is the following true?

The rational expectations hypothesis also implicitly assumes that the law of motion of the economy does not change, which actually is a self-fulfilling assumption as long as all agents behave rationally. However, this is not longer true in models that introduce boundedly rational agents.